# Is there away to know if a user is still on my site - instead of using cookies or sessions

Tags: php, jquery, tracking, cron-task

I am wondering, if there is a real-time way time ping a user and see if that user is still only.

My site uses jQuery, PHP and CRON jobs
so I was wondering what would be the best way to check that the user is still online.

Each user is issues a cookie aka session key but I don't want to just go by that.

I know real-time analytics are able to it, using javascript so I wonder if I could also do the same thing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any method you choose will work the same as what you mentioned, it will just update more often.

You can use an ajax call that pings the server every **x** seconds and as soon as that stops you'll know they left at most **x** seconds ago.

A similar option is to use [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) or Flash to hold a socket connection with the server and mark them as logged off the moment that socket connection is broken.

Both these options are a bit more difficult to scale than sessions and cookies.

Answer (score 1):

it could be done via continues ajax call from client but not recommended.

I suggest use flash or something like that to reduce number of ajax request to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Question is very confused and ambiguous.

No you can't 'ping' a user. You can ping an IP adderss - but the IP addresses you see at your server probably don't map on a one-to-one basis with users.

Which user? All users? Why? What will you do with the information? Have you got a better reason than "I don't want to" for not using session data?

"I know real-time analytics are able to" - then you must know the method they use to do this - or are you just buying the sales speak?

Comment: I don't think it's that ambiguous.  Maybe not perfectly worded for an expert, but the basic idea of what he's asking is there.  He received 3 similar answers, which is to say people understood the question.  I assume you understood it as well.  I think the condescending tone in this "answer" is unnecessary.  Otherwise, I think your follow-up questions are perfectly valid, albeit better suited for comments.

Comment: We are only wanting to know if the user is still active on our site. NOTHING ELSE is being stored.

Answer (score 0):

I guess only way to get "real-time" data is to use web-sockets.

another way which is less acurate ( with delay ) is to use repited ajax calls. say 1 per 60 seconds.